# Die question - Probability

Tags: probability

I chose a random number from 1 to 6. Afterwards, I roll a die till I get a result that is even or higher than my chosen number. What is the $E(x)$ of the number of times I throw the die?

So I thought it's Geometric distribution will "success" where "success" is to get my number. So first the probability of choosing a random number in the die is $1/6$. Now I can't configure what is the probability to get something even or higher? Since I chose the number randomly. and afterthat, I just need to divide 1 by the probability I get (like the geometric E(x) formula)?

Comment: You have to compute the expectation separately for each choice of the random number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $X$ be uniformly distributed on $\{1,\dotsc, 6\}$ and let $N$ be the number of times that you need to roll the die. Note that $N\mid X=x$ is geometrically distributed with probability mass function
$$
P(N=k\mid X=x)=(1-p)^{k-1} p\quad ({k\geq 1})
$$
where $p=\frac{6-x+1}{6}$. The law of total expectation yields that
$$
EN=E(EN\mid X)=E\frac{6}{6-X+1}
=6E\frac{1}{6-X+1}=6\times\frac{1}{6}\left(1+\frac{1}{2}\dotsb\frac{1}{6}\right).$$
So
$$
EN=\sum_{k=1}^6\frac{1}{k}
$$